# Madden 2011 Rushing Tips

Tags: xbox-360, madden-11

I am looking for some Madden 2011 rushing tips. Does anyone have any?

I can generally get past a couple guys, but I can never get past contact.  I have tried leaning into it as well as covering the ball, but really just suck at running!

Comment: Could you be more specific? What kinds of tips are you looking for? Which players to use? How to control the players? Are you having any particular problems?

Answer (score 1):

Follow your blockers. Know what you're blockers are going to do, and wait for them to block before you run past them.

Mix up your play calling and formations. Don't always run from the same formations. Watch out for a stacked box. Run some play action.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big time passer, but this also allows me to rip off big runs from the shotgun. You need a fast RB (at least 88+ speed). Draw's aren't the best, but they can work. My favorite run is a sweep out of the shotgun.

If your going to do this though you really need to use the New England Patriots playbook. It has every shotgun formation on the game. You can even fake a screen pass and then do a draw which can be very effective. They also have a HB direct snap which I like for 2-PT conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Trucking is one of the best ways to get yards after contact. Running backs with high Trucking will be able to break more tackles; occasionally this will happen even if you are not actively trying to break a tackle with the Hit Stick. I've done pretty well at that with Kevin Smith (85 trucking in season 2 of our online franchise league) ... on more than one occasion, I've given up on advancing and tucked the ball, only to realize that I wasn't down, able to run for a score.

Like Colin said, wait for your blockers: don't sprint as soon as you have the ball. On power plays especially, you'll have a tendency to get to the defenders before your blockers do. Run at normal speed until you have a gap and then hit it.

Remember that protecting the ball will slow down your RB. Don't worry about it at least until someone is approaching you.